# How to call print function after page is loaded?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So on click i want to call print function, but after partial page is loaded?
I dont want to use $timeout, i tried with angular.element(document).ready but partial view is render after print function is called.Any suggestion?

EDIT: I tried this :

```
   var w = $window.open("/account/ticketprint");
 angular.element(document).ready(function () {
           w.print();
});
```

Comment: Replicate the "partial" view you presumably want with a print media stylesheet then print onload?

Comment: Share us any code wrt what you have tried?

Comment: @deostroll there i posted what i tried

Comment: @AlexK. im not sure what u mean?

Comment: you are trying to print what appears in a pop up? You need to run window.print() in **that** document, not in the "opener" page document...

Comment: Yes im trying to print what appears in pop up, but how will i "tell it" to print in that document ? :D

Comment: You need javascript on that page...or try giving `w.document` to the ready function...I guess it is that...else use console.log on `w` to find that document object...and again...you need to do this on that page's window load event...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82609/discussion-between-none-and-deostroll).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind to that page's window's onload event and then print...

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $window) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.print = function() {
    var w = $window.open($window.location.href + '#/?_=2323232');
    console.log(w);
    angular.element(w).bind('load', function() {
      w.print();
    });
  };
});
```

Plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/DDGsWBnwmfjWHCrKwxlZ?p=preview

Comment: can u come in disscussion chat a littlebit more?

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to do it

1.$timeout():- it will run in next digest cycle after th html is rendered

2.$scope.$evalAsync():- it will run before angular get rendered on Html

So you can use accordingly

Comment: i cant find anything about $scope.$async